# C++ Win32 MessageBox weird output

Tags: c++, messagebox

I am not quite sure why this is happening. I am just trying to output the key pressed. Breakpoint shows the correct letter stored in the pressed variable. Project is set to Unicode.

```
case WM_CHAR:
    {
        const wchar_t pressed = LOWORD(wParam);
        ::MessageBox(hWnd, &pressed, L"Key Pressed", MB_OK);
    }
```

Comment: I am not quite sure. It looks like a long list of repeated Japanese symbols or something.

Comment: You are passing the address of 'pressed' not it's value

Comment: I have to. The function requires a pointer, and I am not able to set the variable to a pointer because then I get an error with LOWORD. Not sure how to change it.

Comment: It actually displays the letter, but after that it is filled with weird symbols.

Comment: Because you didn't terminate the string properly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I think the MessageBox was continuing to displaying memory items past the memory address of the wchar_t variable. I had to convert that letter to a wstring, and then pass that to the MessageBox.

Comment: The reason that solved the problem is because the `std::wstring` class *automatically* null-terminates strings. All C strings must end with a null-character (`\0`), that's how it knows it found the end of the string. The `MessageBox` function is no different, as it is a C function. Read up to learn more about null-terminated strings. However, promptly forget as much of that as possible, because in C++ you should *always* use either `std::wstring` or `std::string`.